# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar un FloatingActionButton de forma programática en Android?

Tags: android, material-ui

Tengo definido un FloatingActionButton en Android con un icono por defecto.

En el XML este es el botón:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_surface"
                android:text="@string/enviar_email"
                />
```

Y en los estilos, adquiere una imagen por defecto:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.FloatingActionButton" parent="">
    <item name="colorContainer">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="icon">@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email</item>
    <item name="colorOnContainer">@color/colorMainIcon</item>
</style>
```

Mi problema es que en un escenario concreto, quiero cambiar el icono `ic_dialog_email` por este otro: `ic_refresh_black_24dp`. Para ello, he intentado hacerlo de forma programática, pero no funciona, porque el icono se cambia, pero no respeta las dimensiones, el icono se sobrepone, apareciendo más grande.

He intentado con esto, habiendo leído algunas sugerencias, y no funciona:

```
    Drawable img = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_refresh_black_24dp);
    mButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(img, null, null, null);
```

Y también con esto:

```
    Drawable img = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_refresh_black_24dp);
    mButton.setBackground(img);
```

Aquí sí se coloca el icono, pero comiéndose el botón, por decirlo de alguna manera.

El botón original se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y al cambiarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el icono correctamente de forma programática?

Comment: Tiene sentido porque el fondo es todo el botón. Tal vez con la función [`setIcon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) que hereda de `MaterialButton` puedas hacerlo.

Comment: @Mateo no me daba la opción de un método `setIcon()`, por lo que deduje que el elemento no posee dicho método. El problema es que había declarado el elemento como `private Button mButton;`, lo he cambiado por **`private MaterialButton mButton;`** y ahora sí me acepta `setIcon()` y, efectivamente así ha funcionado. Agradezco lo pongas como respuesta. Gracias a tu sugerencia he dado con el problema.

Comment: Recuerda que los objetos se ven limitados por su *contenedor*. Me gusta pensar las variables y el polimorfismo de ese modo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [`setBackground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) es para cambiar el fondo del botón.

[`ExtendedFloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/ExtendedFloatingActionButton) hereda dos métodos llamados [`setIcon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) y [`setIconResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#setIconResource(int)).

Deberías poder usarlos para cambiar el ícono.

```
ExtendedFloatingActionButton button;

...

button.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_refresh_black_24dp);
```

Comment: Ha fucionado perfecto declarando el objeto del tipo `ExtendedFloatingActionButton ` y usando simplemente: `setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_refresh_black_24dp)`. Muchísimas gracias.